# Boot freezes at “Started Hold until boot process finishes up”

Tags: fedora

I've updated fedora system, and new kernel was installed. Unfortunatelly, when I try to boot it, it freezes with on message “Started Hold until boot process finishes up”. Trying to google answer it showed, that typical issue is lack of free space. That's not my case.

I'm beginner, what can I do to fix this? Or where can I find relevant information what went wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my case was caused by need to reinstall Nvidia drivers for new kernel.